# Edit output of a pre-compiled generic handler .ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've inherited a pre-compiled website that uses javascript created in a generic handler (ashx).  I need to modify the js, but I dont have the source, only the pre-compiled libraries.  Currently, we're simply doing an http request on the ashx, modifying the result and then outputting it directly on the site:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected string getJs()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(Request.Url, "/js.ashx"));
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        return = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("old stuff", "new stuff");
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= getJs() %>
</script>
```

This seems like a pretty round-about way of doing this.  Is there anyway to modify the output of a generic handler without requesting the page itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try dis-assembling the pre-compiled piece, if you have access to the actual `dll`.
See [converting-il-to-c-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648051/converting-il-to-c-code) and similar SO questions.

Using [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) you may have a workable (C#) version of the code behind `js.ashx`.
This source can (hopefully) be slightly modified to be directly callable, or better, to produce the desired Javascript.