# Iterate through Linq fluent API methods (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, ienumerable, iqueryable

I am looking for a way to iterate through a collection of Linq methods, previously built, and then manipulate them, like change the expression tree.

Here is an example:

[image]

what i simply want to do is a forEach (or something of sorts) to get a cycle where:

i get the linq `.Where(e => e.Summary == "sum")` in the first position

i get the linq `.Where(l => l.Description == "asd")` in the second position

i get the linq `.Take(2)` in the last iteration

Is this possible? Most likely with reflection, but i could do it or find it.

**Other Example**

Using the example above, i want to peek that Ienumerable/Iqueryable and get the first *where*, getting the **equivalent** result:

```
var c = list
        .Where(e => e.Summary == "sum");
```

Let me emphasise, i want this via runtime, with the Ienumerable/Iqueryable as an input.

Thank you,

Comment: Is this maybe the direction you are going for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-5.0 ? See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Comment: You want to loop on what to do what? What do you call a cycle? What is the link with linq chaining or reflexion?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is clear enough. Please provide example of what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Mind: _"Expression trees should be immutable. This means that if you want to modify an expression tree, you must construct a new expression tree by copying the existing one and replacing nodes in it."_ - [Immutability of Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/#immutability-of-expression-trees)

Comment: I added an example that maybe can be more simple to grasp

Comment: I will close this question. I want to make this approach in EF core, but i was removing it altogether to avoid confusion, but was a mistake. I will simply make a new implementation of the DBContext and make some sort of wrapper. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is by creating new functions (such as `_Where()`, `_Take()`) that just call the `Where` and `Take` function, but also save the fact that you called them and with which arguments. Then later you can read them again.

The downside of this is that you need to somehow store which calls belong to which. I.e. if you have two statements `list.Where().Where()` and `list.Where().Take()` you need to save which calls belong to the first line and which belong to the second.

You could also try to make these sepcialized functions return a tuple containing both the result and the call information. Then you should create two functions for each linq method: one which just accepts an enumerable and one which accepts a tuple of an enumerable and the call information from before. This way you can add the new call information to the old one. If you use extension functions, you have to extend the enumerable and the tuple of course.

**Edit**:

Let me add an example of my thinking... Note that it is difficult to perfectly serialize the function given in the `Where` function. It is possible, check for example [Convert Func delegate to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067873/)

Overloads.cs:

```cs
public static class Overloads
{
    public static (IEnumerable<T>, List<string>) Where_<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inp, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return (inp.Where(predicate), new List<string> { ".Where(...)" });
    }

    public static (IEnumerable<T>, List<string>) Where_<T>(this (IEnumerable<T>, List<string>) inp, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        inp.Item2.Add(".Where(...)");
        return (inp.Item1.Where(predicate), inp.Item2);
    }

    public static (IEnumerable<T>, List<string>) Take_<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inp, int count)
    {
        return (inp.Take(count), new List<string> { $".Take({count})" });
    }

    public static (IEnumerable<T>, List<string>) Take_<T>(this (IEnumerable<T>, List<string>) inp, int count)
    {
        inp.Item2.Add($".Take({count})");
        return (inp.Item1.Take(count), inp.Item2);
    }
}
```

Example run:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    var (result, calls) = a
        .Where_(x => x % 2 == 0)
        .Where_(x => x % 3 == 0)
        .Take_(1);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", calls));
}
```

Output:

```
0
.Where(...), .Where(...), .Take(1)
```

Comment: Good answer. I think for me the best of two worlds would be in fact do a new override implementation of this extension methods, that store this behaviors.  What you think  ?

Comment: I think you should go for the approach with tuples for cleanliness, please check my answer... HTH